# Best way to update combobox entries that are bound to an attribute of custom class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox that is bound to a List  property.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSeriesComboBoxProperty}"  .. >
```

```
private List<String> _dataSeriesEntries;
public List<String> DataSeriesComboBoxProperty
{
     get { return _dataSeriesEntries; }
     set
     {
           _dataSeriesEntries = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("DataSeriesComboBoxProperty");
     }
}
```

The property is a list where each entry is the name attribut from a custom class.

```
DataSeriesComboBoxProperty = DataSeriesList.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.Name);

public List<DataSeriesDowngraded> DataSeriesList { get; set; }
```

Now I would like, that as soon as in DataSeriesList an entry is added, this is also visible in the combobox. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Just to be sure: You have one List with DataSeriesDowngraded and a List with the names from all these DataSeriesDowngraded?

Comment: not necessarily. But DataSeriesList is a property in the datacontext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `List<DataSeriesComboBoxProperty>`, just delete it.

Change your `List<DataSeriesDowngraded>` to `ObservableCollection<DataSeriesDowngraded>`, include a backing field and `OnPropertyChanged`.

Should look likes this

```
private ObservableCollection<DataSeriesDowngraded> _dataSeries;
public ObservableCollection<DataSeriesDowngraded> DataSeries
{
    get { return _dataSeriesEntries; }
    set
    {
        _dataSeries = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("DataSeries");
    }
}
```

In you xaml change your `ItemsSource` binding of the `ComboBox` to `ItemsSource="{Binding DataSeries}"` and add `DisplayMemberPath="Name"`.

`ObservableCollection` will update your UI when items are added or removed. `List` won't. That's why you should always using `ObservableCollection` when binding collections to your UI.
And you don't need a second list with the names because you can say witch property should be displayed in your `ComboBox`.